# PECL install with clang instead of gcc or optimize gcc

Tags: pecl, gcc

I just tried to PECL install mongodb and phalcon, but the build process ran out of memory with a nice error: `cc: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1)`.
I just found out clang is much better at memory optimization during the build process, but I can't find documentation on how to pecl install using clang instead of gcc. I'm using docker, so I can try things until they work.

Currently, I'm installing clang and NOT gcc, then trying to pecl install, and I get this error:
`configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH`.

Is it possible to either PECL install with clang? or is there another way to get around running out of memory installing with PECL?

Comment: Give your container more memory?

Comment: That is an option… one I was trying to avoid. I have searched high and low for a way to use a different compiler… and probably would have to install an older version of gcc to get around the memory issue based on what I found. I instead found a version of phalcon built as an apk for alpine in a slightly later version and pulled it down with wget and installed it. That is working nicely!